# Can I filter rows by state from address column in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, dataframe

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
customer_id VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
address NVARCHAR(max),
created_time DateTimeOffset NOT NULL default SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
) 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_customer_email
ON Customer(customer_id, Email)

INSERT INTO Customer(id, Name, Email, customer_id, address)
VALUES(0,'a','a@gmail.com','a000', '“house_number”: 10, “building_name”: “B0”, “street”: “street0”,
   “city”: “Guwahati”, “state”: “Assam”, “country” : “India”, “Zipcode” : 781017'),
  (1,'b','b@gmail.com','b001', '“house_number”: 11, “building_name”: “B1”, “street”: “street1”,
   “city”: “Patna”, “state”: “Bihar”, “country” : “India”, “Zipcode” : 801101'),
  (2,'c','c@gmail.com','c002', '“house_number”: 12, “building_name”: “B2”, “street”: “street2”,
   “city”: “Raipur”, “state”: “Chhattisgarh”, “country” : “India”, “Zipcode” : 493661'),
  (3,'d','d@gmail.com','d003', NULL),
  (4,'e','e@gmail.com','e004', '“house_number”: 14, “building_name”: “B4”, “street”: “street4”,
   “city”: “Rajkot”, “state”: “Gujrat”, “country” : “India”, “Zipcode” : 360110'),
  (5,'f','f@gmail.com','f005', '“house_number”: 15, “building_name”: “B5”, “street”: “street5”,
   “city”: “Patipat”, “state”: “Haryana”, “country” : “India”, “Zipcode” : 132113'),
  (6,'g','g@gamil.com','g006', '“house_number”: 16, “building_name”: “B6”, “street”: “street6”,
   “city”: “Bangalore”, “state”: “Karnataka”, “country” : “India”, “Zipcode” : 560101'),
  (7,'h','h@gmail.com','h007', '“house_number”: 17, “building_name”: “B7”, “street”: “street7”,
   “city”: “Nagpur”, “state”: “Maharashtra”, “country” : “India”, “Zipcode” : 440001'),
  (8,'i','i@gmail.com','i008', NULL),
  (9,'j','j@gmail.com','j009', '“house_number”: 19, “building_name”: “B9”, “street”: “street9”,
   “city”: “Amritsar”, “state”: “Punjab”, “country” : “India”, “Zipcode” : 143101')
```

After running the above query I get the following table.
[image]

Now I want to query just the name of states from address column without creating another address table. The expected result will be :
Assam
Bihar
Chhattisgarh
Gujrat
Haryana
Karnataka
Maharashtra

Can the following results be obtained ?
If not kindly provide the alternative.

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because you explicitly mention SQL Server.  What is an example of a "non null" value for "state"?  It is part of a string, not a column.  What results do you want?

Comment: Edit the question add expected result too.

Comment: I have edited the question. Kindly look at it and if you can, please help me with the solutions.

Comment: You have received quite a few answers. Is there any answer that helped you more than others? It'd be best to put a closure to your question by marking an answer as the chosen one.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

Do you mean the whole address line is NULL?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Customer
WHERE   [address] IS NOT NULL;
```

**Option 2:**

Wildcard searches in the text. Assuming that an empty state is "state": "". This method would also be quite inefficient for large volumes of data:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    dbo.Customer
WHERE   ISNULL([address], '') LIKE '%"state": ""%';
```

**Option 3:**

Using JSON to get the fields within the Address field.  I have used `REPLACE` as I wasn't sure if your "" was done via copy and paste or whether they were actually stored that way.  You can remove if it was a copy paste issue:

```
WITH AddressJSON AS
(
SELECT  c.*
,       IIF(c.[address] IS NULL, NULL,  '{ "address": { ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(c.[address], '“', '"'), '”', '"') + ' } }') AS AddressQuotes
FROM    dbo.Customer c
)
SELECT  aj.*
,       JSON_VALUE(aj.AddressQuotes, '$.address.house_number')      AS HouseNumber
,       JSON_VALUE(aj.AddressQuotes, '$.address.building_name')     AS BuildingName
,       JSON_VALUE(aj.AddressQuotes, '$.address.street')            AS Street
,       JSON_VALUE(aj.AddressQuotes, '$.address.city')              AS City
,       JSON_VALUE(aj.AddressQuotes, '$.address.state')             AS [State]
,       JSON_VALUE(aj.AddressQuotes, '$.address.country')           AS Country
,       JSON_VALUE(aj.AddressQuotes, '$.address.Zipcode')           AS Zipcode
FROM    AddressJSON aj
WHERE   JSON_VALUE(aj.AddressQuotes, '$.address.state') IS NOT NULL;
```

The last query yields:
[image]

**Option 4:**

This is based on your amended question:

```
WITH AddressJSON AS
(
SELECT  c.*
,       IIF(c.[address] IS NULL, NULL,  '{ "address": { ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(c.[address], '“', '"'), '”', '"') + ' } }') AS AddressQuotes
FROM    dbo.Customer c
)
SELECT      TRIM(STRING_AGG(JSON_VALUE(AddressQuotes, '$.address.state'), ' ' )) AS AddState
FROM        AddressJSON
WHERE       JSON_VALUE(AddressQuotes, '$.address.state') IS NOT NULL;
```

Which yields a result of:

[image]

Comment: I want my result to look like: [Assam Bihar Chhattisgarh Gujrat Haryana Karnataka Maharashtra]. And 2nd option is displaying any value. Can you suggest some alternative.

Comment: Hopefully the answer above helps @ShubhamKumar

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 and above , you can use JSON_VALUE to extract the state from the address column and check for nulls.

If you can change table schema, you can also create a separate table for address and add addressed column on the customer table.Then you can use join query and filter non null values

Comment: Care to provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `apply` and `string_split` to get the results.

try the following:

```
select c.*, trim(replace(replace(replace(value, '“state”:', ''),'“', ''), '”', '')) [State]
from Customer c
cross apply (select * from string_split([address], ','))t
where t.value like '%state%'
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5df748bb722bb967bca0a9203cdbf607)**.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZbEE.png)
Is this what you are looking for? This answer is based on  answer provided by Raymondo

```
DECLARE @StateList VARCHAR(8000)

WITH AddressJSON AS
(
SELECT  c.*
,       IIF(c.[address] IS NULL, NULL,  '{ "address": { ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(c.[address], '“', '"'), '”', '"') + ' } }') AS AddressQuotes
FROM    dbo.Customer c
)

SELECT
      @StateList = COALESCE(@StateList + ',', '')  + JSON_VALUE(aj.AddressQuotes, '$.address.state')           
FROM    AddressJSON aj
WHERE   JSON_VALUE(aj.AddressQuotes, '$.address.state') IS NOT NULL;

SELECT @StateList as StateList
```

Answer (score 0):

From another question you asked, it seems like you are using SQL Server 2019.

You could simply use:

```
select distinct JSON_VALUE(concat('{', address, '}'), '$.state')
from customer;
```

to get a list of all unique states.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2ff561/4

to get one state per row.

---

You can also string aggregate like so:

```
select 
STRING_AGG(
  JSON_VALUE(concat('{', address, '}'), '$.state'),
  ' '
)
from customer;
```

to get `Assam Bihar Chhattisgarh Gujrat Haryana Karnataka Maharashtra Punjab`

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2ff561/7