# How to create a table address and query it by states?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How can I create a table with following schema:

[image: How can I create a table with following schema]

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    customer_id VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    address NVARCHAR(max),
    created_time DateTimeOffset NOT NULL default SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_customer_email
ON Customer(customer_id, Email)
```

I wrote the above query for creating the table.

But I'm not able to link this table to another table for the query shown below and fetch all state names and total of account balance for the users belonging to those states.

```
CREATE TABLE Account
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    account_no VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    account_balance DECIMAL(16,2),
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_date DateTimeOffset NOT NULL default SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Customer(id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

CREATE INDEX idx_user_account
ON Account(user_id, account_balance)
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you have?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Comment: downvote for [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837781/can-i-filter-rows-by-state-from-address-column-in-ms-sql-server). And follow the instructions. Why use nvarchar when it specifically mentions json?

Comment: That was also my question that how to create a column with JSON data in SQL Server 2019 ? As I didn't knew I used NVARCHAR instead. So I had to post for the 2nd time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this to query out records:

```
select
  a.*,
  JSON_VALUE(address, '$.state') as state,
  b.account_id
from customer a
inner join account b on a.id = b.user_id
where JSON_VALUE(a.address, '$.state') = 'maharashtra';
```

Let's take an example.

```
insert into customer (id, name, email, customer_id, address) values
(
  1,
  'john parker',
  'a@a',
  'abc',
  '{"house_number":"10", "building_number": "manyata", "street": "vivekanand street", "city": "nagpur", "state": "maharashtra", "country": "india", "zipcode": "440001"}'
),
(
  2,
  'john parker',
  'a@b',
  'abc',
  '{"house_number":"10", "building_number": "manyata", "street": "vivekanand street", "city": "nagpur", "state": "gujarat", "country": "india", "zipcode": "392020"}'
);
```

These are two records - one for maharashtra and one for gujarat.

In your account able, you have 2 records as well like so:

```
insert into Account (id, account_id, account_no, user_id) values
(1, 'test', 'test', 1),
(2, 'test2', 'test2', 2);
```

When you run the query, you will get results for just maharastra.

See example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c56741/1

Comment: The first query is not properly working. It shows an error "SON text is not properly formatted"

Comment: On your database, run this `select * from customer` and take a screenshot of the output in full and add it to your question. There may be something wrong in the JSON data stored in address.

Comment: @ShubhamKumar if your json does not start and end with `{` and `}`, change `JSON_VALUE(a.address, '$.state')` to `JSON_VALUE(concat('{', a.address, '}', '$.state')`. I have tested it out with an example on SQLFiddle. It should work for you as well. If not, feel free to share some test data and I can help further. If you have your question answered (this one and the other one you just asked), please put closure to your question by marking one of the answers as the chosen one.

Comment: Initially I forgot to add { and }, after adding the above solution is working fine.

Comment: I have imported the data in Python and converted the table into a data frame. Now I want to do the same operation there. How can I do that ?  If you know, kindly help me out.